# unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11'

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, codeblocks

`CodeBlocks` keeps giving me this error even though there is no `-std=c++11` option enabled (I checked all the settings and the project file).

Is there A way to disable this?

Comment: I attempted to enable that but for some reason "-std=c++11" is still being called.

Answer (score 5):

This is my best guess. The compiler you are using to build the project
is gcc. You have `-std=c++11` set in your *global* settings
for this compiler but the installed version of gcc is too old to
recognize the option.

To check this out in the Code::Blocks IDE:

- Navigate *Settings -> Compiler*
- From the drop-down menu labelled *Selected compiler*, select the *GNU GCC compiler*
- On the tab-panel below, select *Compiler settings -> Compiler flags*
- From the drop-down menu labelled "Categories", select *`<All categories>`*.
- Look down the check-box list of compiler options until you see:

> Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]

- If that check-box is checked then that is probably your problem. Uncheck it, click OK,
  and then try to rebuild your project.

If that fixes the problem, you should consider upgrading gcc to a version (>= 4.7)
that supports the `-std=c++11` option as you will then have support for the C++
language and library features of the latest C++ standard.

If you cannot do that, you may find that the `-std=c++0x` option is acceptable
to your compiler. If that works, it will provide support for some provisional 
version of the C++11 standard that was operative when your compiler was released.

A less likely scenario than the above is that the compiler you are using to
build the project is not gcc but some other and non-commandline-compatible
compiler than you have set up in Code::Blocks by copying GCC's global 
configuration, in which the `-std-c++11` option is set. In that case you just
have to ensure that no global options are configured for this compiler that
it does not recognize.

For your future reference, if you have a problem with the commandline options
of a c++ compiler, say what compiler it is, and what version.

Comment: I found the problem before you answered, but the problem was it was checked in the global settings. Anyway I still need to check my compiler version.

Comment: It's MinGW 4.6.2. Is that old?

Comment: @MonetR.Adams Yes, that is too old for `-std-c++11` (you need >= 4.7) but it will accept `-std=c++0x`.